# List index Err : Index was out of range

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two lists and I want to copy data from one to another and I get this error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

Here's my code:

```
static  IList<Common.Data.Driver> Stt_driverList = new List<Common.Data.Driver>();
List<Common.Data.Driver> driverList = new List<Common.Data.Driver>();

for (int i = 0; i < driverList.Count; i++)
{
    //Fill in The Static Driver List
    Stt_driverList[i] = driverList[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stt_driverList` does not contain any items when you start looping, so you can't refer to elements by index. Try using the `Add` method instead:

```
static IList Stt_driverList = new List();
IList driverList = new List();
for (int i = 0; i < driverList.Count; i++)
{
    //Fill in The Static Driver List
    Stt_driverList.Add(driverList[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the indexer to increase the size of a list; only to modify existing entries. You could use `Add` instead... but it would be simpler to just copy the whole list in one go:

```
Stt_driverList = new List<Common.Data.Driver>(driverList);
```

That constructor just performs a shallow copy in a single call.

If that's not what you want, there's probably still a good way of avoiding looping explicitly - give us more details and we may be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Stt_driverList.Add(...), also take a look at the function AddRange().